# Any other web Analytics tool other than Google Analytics

Tags: google, google-analytics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a better analytics package than Google Analytics?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/19/is-there-a-better-analytics-package-than-google-analytics)

Is there any other more advanced web analytics tool than Google Analytics? Even though Google Analytics fulfills all my requirements now, I was just curious to know if someone had stumbled upon a better tool.

Regards,
Loveleen

Comment: Yes you have. Matomo (former Piwik) is a tool you can use for free. Only thing: you have to host the data yourself. For websites with little traffic this does not have to be a problem. But when the daily server capacity is "full" it trows data away. So only a real option when you have enough server room or you need a data sensitive tool.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is yes, longer answer is how much can you afford to pay for it?

The Market leading software is omniture sitecatalyst and webtrends live. But both are paid for tools and as an experienced user of both I'll tell you for free that GA does almost everything they do and just as well. When google bought out urchin they were tied for third in the analytics marketplace.

I've worked at multi-million pound companies who pay thousands for analytics that GA would do just as well.